# Multiply all numbers between given two numbers in for loops

Tags: javascript

I ask user for first number. Then I ask for a number bigger than first. Multiply all the numbers from the first number to the second and output the results.

I have it working as a while loop but need to switch it into a for loop. I keep getting the wrong value for multiply when I attempt to switch it into a for loop. Not sure what is needed to be done.

```
const INITIAL_VALUE = 0;

// declare variables
var number1;
var number2;
var multiply;
var middlePoint;

// initialize sum
multiply = INITIAL_VALUE;

// prompt user to enter two numbers
number1 = prompt("Enter first number: ");
number2 = prompt("Enter a number bigger than first number: ");

// convert user input into numbers
number1 = Number(number1);
number2 = Number(number2);

// assign middlePoint
middlePoint = number1;

// display number1
document.write(number1);

// assign multiply and increment middlePoint
multiply = middlePoint;
middlePoint++;

// while loop to display numbers in between and multiply
//**NEEDS TO BE A FOR LOOP, NOT A WHILE LOOP**
while (middlePoint < number2) {
    document.write(" * " + middlePoint);
    multiply *= middlePoint;
    middlePoint++;
}

// add multiply to number2 for final multiplication total
multiply *= number2;

// display number2 and final multiplication total
document.write(" * " + number2 + " = " + multiply);
```

Comment: there is no for loop in your code

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

For switching to `for` loop, simply make sure that the number of loop is the same as the `while` loop. In this case, the number of loop to be made is `number2 - number1 - 1` or the amount of number between `number2` and `number1`. Therefore, your `for` loop will be:

```
for (var i=0; i<number2-number1-1; i++) {
    document.write(" * " + middlePoint);
    multiply *= middlePoint;
    middlePoint++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is written to take a while loop. Transitioning to a for loop is messier than using a while loop, as you're checking a Boolean condition. However, if you really want a for  loop, here you go:

```
for (;middlePoint < number2;) {
    document.write(" * " + middlePoint);
    multiply *= middlePoint;
    middlePoint++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code to multiply all numbers from n1 to n2: `mul` will contain the multiplication result:

```js
var mul = 1;
    var firstNumber = 0;
    var secondNUmber = 0;
    var firstNumberStr = '';
    var secondNUmberStr = '';

    // prompt user to enter two numbers
    firstNumberStr = prompt("Enter first number: ");

    while(isNaN(firstNumberStr)){
        firstNumberStr = prompt("Enter Correct first number: ");
    }

    secondNUmberStr = prompt("Enter a number bigger than first number: ");

    while(isNaN(secondNUmberStr) || parseInt(firstNumberStr) >= parseInt(secondNUmberStr)){
        secondNUmberStr = prompt("Enter a number bigger than first number: ");
    }

    firstNumber = parseInt(firstNumberStr); 
    secondNUmber = parseInt(secondNUmberStr);
    
    for(;firstNumber <= secondNUmber;){
        mul *= firstNumber;
        firstNumber++   
    } 
    
    alert(mul);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be modified as below:

```js
// declare variables
var number1;
var number2;
var multiply;
var middlePoint;
const INITIAL_VALUE = 0;
// initialize sum
multiply = INITIAL_VALUE;

// prompt user to enter two numbers
number1 = prompt("Enter first number: ");
number2 = prompt("Enter a number bigger than first number: ");

// convert user input into numbers
number1 = Number(number1);
number2 = Number(number2);

// assign middlePoint
middlePoint = number1;

// display number1
document.write(number1);

// assign multiply and increment middlePoint
multiply = middlePoint;
middlePoint++;

// while loop to display numbers in between and multiply
for (var i=0;middlePoint < number2; i++) {
    document.write(" * " + middlePoint);
    multiply *= middlePoint;
    middlePoint++;
}

// add multiply to number2 for final multiplication total
multiply *= number2;

// display number2 and final multiplication total
document.write(" * " + number2 + " = " + multiply);
```

Comment: what is the need of variable i, isnt middlePoint enough to serve the purpose?

Comment: It is just a for loop variable. As the code on the original post is working fine, it does not require to modify his code. So just I used for loop in the place of while loop..

Comment: The above code is working well after converting while loop into for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
let number1, number2, result, resultText;

// prompt user to enter two numbers
number1 = prompt('Enter first number: ');
number2 = prompt('Enter a number bigger than first number: ');

// convert user input into numbers
number1 = Number(number1);
number2 = Number(number2);

// Initialize result and resultText
result = number1;
resultText = '' + number1; 

// for loop to display numbers in between and multiply
for (let i = 1; i <= number2 - number1; i++) {
  const temp = number1 + i;
  result *= temp;
  resultText += ' * ' + temp;
}

// display final multiplication total
resultText += ' = ' + result;
document.write(resultText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is finding the product of all numbers between given two numbers in for loops,
simplified code

```js
var num1 = 10;
var num2 = 20;
var product = 1;

document.write(num1);
num1 ++; 

for (;num1 <= num2;) {
    document.write(" * " + num1);
    product *= num1;
    num1++;
}

// display final product
document.write(" = " + product);
```